# Determining Infinity Norm

Tags: linear-algebra, normed-spaces

I am trying to follow along with a practice problem in my book that asks me to determine the distance between two vectors $\textbf{u} = (-2, 2, 1)^{T}$ and $\textbf{v} = (1, 4, 1)^{T}$ using the $\infty$-norm.  The answer they have is
$$
\lVert \textbf{u} - \textbf{v} \rVert_{2} = \sqrt{13}
$$

but isn't this also the Euclidean norm?
$$
\sqrt{(-2 - 1)^{2} + (2 - 4)^{2} + (1 - 1)^{2}} \:=\: \sqrt{13}
$$

From my understanding, the $\infty$-norm is the max entry (in absolute value) of a vector. Wouldn't that make it
$$
\text{max}(\,|-2-1|,\: |2 - 4|,\: |1-1|\,) \:=\: 3
$$

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You are right, the book is wrong. Probably a cut and paste o.

Comment: Well, they didn't make a mistake, but the $2$-norm is not the $\infty$-norm, so they answered a different question. Both equations, $\|u-v\|_\infty = 3, \|u-v\|_2 = \sqrt{13}$ are correct, though.

Comment: That would make sense because another part of the problem is to determine the distance using the Euclidean norm.

Comment: @AlexR For the sake of moving this question off the unanswered list, would you mind posting your comment as an answer?

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt [last seen Mar 4](http://math.stackexchange.com/users/220768/linear-algebra-guy). Seems like the question was abandoned anyway so an answer will not get accepted.

Comment: @AlexR The question would be removed from the unanswered list if the answer has a positive score.

Comment: @PeterWoolfitt Oh, I didn't know that. I posted the comment as an answer now.

Answer (score 1):

*Converted to an answer by request.*

Well, they didn't make a mistake, but the $2$-norm is not the $\infty$-norm, so they answered a different question. Both equations, $\|u−v\|_\infty=3$ and $\|u−v\|_2=\sqrt{13}$ are correct, though.